# Examples of rare, meager and nonmeager sets in $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, baire-category

Kreyszig Functional Analysis book presents the following definition.

[image]

I'm trying to get some examples.

**(a)** The cantor set $K$ is rare in $\mathbb{R}$ because it's closed and has empty interior so that $$\operatorname{int}\left(\overline{K}\right)=\operatorname{int}(K)=\varnothing.$$

**(b)** The set $\mathbb{Q}$ of rationals numbers is meager in $\mathbb{R}$ because it's enumerable so that we can write $$\mathbb{Q}=\{r_1,r_2,...,r_n,...\}=\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty{\{r_i}\},$$ where $\{r_i\}$ is rare for all $i\in\mathbb{N}$.

**(c)** I think that $(0,1)$ (like any other non-degenerate interval) is a nonmeager set in $\mathbb{R}$. My question is: how to prove it?.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think anyone is using "rare" as a terminology anymore. Or maybe ever? (Except the author of that book...)

Comment: Do you know the Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: @Asaf: Are you saying that _rare_ is rare?

Comment: @Arthur: He is, and ’tis well done!

Comment: @ArthurFischer the author proves the Baire Category Theorem after this definition. In this book, this theorem states: "if a metric space $X\neq\varnothing$ is complete, it is nonmeager in itself".

Comment: @ArthurFischer If $(0,1)$ is not nonmeager, then $[0,1]=(0,1)\cup\{0\}\cup\{1\}$ isn't nonmeager. This contradicts the  Baire Category Theorem so that $(0,1)$ is nonmeager. Is this the solution that you suggested?

Comment: @Pedro: Not quite.  I'm about to post an answer.  (Though your idea appears to work.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first two examples are spot on.

Actually, so is the third.

The proof of this relies on the Baire Category Theorem, mentioned in the comments above.

> **Baire Category Theorem:** If a metric space $X\neq\varnothing$ is complete, it is nonmeager in itself.

To see this, recall that any non-degenerate open interval $(a,b)$ is homeomorphic to the real line $\mathbb{R}$.  As $\mathbb{R}$ is a complete metric space, it follows that $(a,b)$ is completely metrizable (of course, the usual metric is not complete on $(a,b)$, but some *other* metric — one derived from a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ — makes it complete).  Therefore $(a,b)$ is nonmeagre-in-itself by the Baire Category Theorem.

If $(a,b) = \bigcup_n Z_n$ where each $Z_n$ is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$, it would follow that each $Z_n$ is also nowhere dense in the subspace $(a,b)$, which would then contradict the fact that $(a,b)$ is nonmeagre-in-itself.

---

A quick comment about your second example: It is good that you note that the singleton sets in $\mathbb{R}$ are nowhere dense.  For instance, $\mathbb{N}$ is countable, but not meagre-in-itself, because $\mathbb{N}$ is discrete (all subsets are open) and so the singleton sets are not nowhere dense in $\mathbb{N}$.  (Of course, $\mathbb{N}$ is meagre in $\mathbb{R}$.)